# A question on the paper "The classification of algebras by dominant dimension"

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

I'm reading the paper "the classification of algebras by dominant dimension" by Bruno J.Mueller, the link is here http://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1968-037-9.

In the proof of lemma 3 on page 402, there is a place I can't understand.[image]

Who can tell me what $E_R \oplus * \cong \oplus X_R$ and $_AHom_R(E,X)\oplus * \cong \oplus _AHom_R(X,X)\cong \oplus_AA$ mean?

Comment: I haven't carefully checked that it makes sense in context, but I would guess $*$ here is just a placeholder variable.  So for instance, the first statement means there exists a module $M$ such that $E_R\oplus M\cong \bigoplus X_R$.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Thank you, sir. I think it makes sense here.